Restringir los resultados a las N primeras filas por grupo
Tengo la siguiente consulta:
SELECT
    codigov, rut, cantidad,referencia
FROM h
WHERE tipomov="R"
ORDER BY referencia,codigo DESC

codigo| rut | cantidad |referencia
5     | 1   |  10      |15
5     | 4   |  10      |14
7     | 01  |  30      |13
4     | 81  |  40      |12
5     | 41  |  55      |11
5     | 41  |  31      |10
7     | 11  |  51      |9
9     | 13  |  31      |8
1     | 11  |  25      |7
5     | 12  |  43      |6
5     | 31  |  31      |5
1     | 13  |  13      |4
1     | 12  |  31      |3
1     | 62  |  13      |2 
5     | 31  |  13      |1

Lo que deseo obtener un limit 3 por codigo, ordenados por referencia descendente y despues por codigo. Es decir un ejemplo así
codigo| rut | cantidad |referencia
5     | 1   |  10      |15
5     | 4   |  10      |14
5     | 41  |  31      |10
1     | 11  |  25      |7
1     | 13  |  13      |4
1     | 12  |  31      |3
7     | 01  |  30      |13
4     | 81  |  40      |12
10    | 41  |  55      |11    
7     | 11  |  51      |9
9     | 13  |  31      |8
10    | 12  |  43      |6    
25    | 31  |  13      |1

En este caso,el codigo 5 y uno estan limitados por 3 registros y ordenados.
Existe la funcion ROW_NUMBER() OVER, pero en mi version de MySql, no la tiene.
Si alguien tiene idea, le agradecería, desde ya, gracias.

Podrías resolverlo haciendo uso de variables que pones a 1 cada vez que el código cambia e incrementas cuando no. Al final te quedas con los registros en los que esa variable valga 3 o menos.
SET @i:=1,@codigo:=0;
SELECT codigo,rut,cantidad,referencia
  FROM (
    SELECT *,
      IF(@codigo!=codigo,@i:=1,@i:=@i+1) orden,
      IF(@codigo!=codigo,@codigo:=codigo,'') codigos
      FROM h
      ORDER BY codigo,referencia DESC
  ) c1
  WHERE orden<=3
  ORDER BY codigo,referencia DESC;

Partiendo de este dataset:
CREATE TABLE h (
  codigo INT,
  rut INT,
  cantidad INT,
  referencia INT
);

INSERT INTO h (codigo, rut, cantidad, referencia) VALUES
(5,1,10,15),
(5,4,10,14),
(7,01,30,13),
(4,81,40,12),
(5,41,55,11),
(5,41,31,10),
(7,11,51,9),
(9,13,31,8),
(1,11,25,7),
(5,12,43,6),
(5,31,31,5),
(1,13,13,4),
(1,12,31,3),
(1,62,13,2),
(5,31,13,1);

Obtendrías:
+--------+------+----------+------------+
| codigo | rut  | cantidad | referencia |
+--------+------+----------+------------+
|      1 |   11 |       25 |          7 |
|      1 |   13 |       13 |          4 |
|      1 |   12 |       31 |          3 |
|      4 |   81 |       40 |         12 |
|      5 |    1 |       10 |         15 |
|      5 |    4 |       10 |         14 |
|      5 |   41 |       55 |         11 |
|      7 |    1 |       30 |         13 |
|      7 |   11 |       51 |          9 |
|      9 |   13 |       31 |          8 |
+--------+------+----------+------------+

Espero que te haya resultado útil. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.
